# QVideoFrame toImage() API memory leak

Tags: qt, opencv, memory-leaks, qt6

I'm using QVideoFrame::toImage() to convert a video frame to OpenCV mat. Visual Studio is showing a huge memory leak every time the function is called. I'm using QT 6.5

This is the code that I'm debugging. I'm getting a video frame from a video sink, converting it to cv::mat and emitting a signal with the data.

```
QVideoFrame frame = playerSink.videoFrame();
if (frame.isValid())
{
    QImage testImage = frame.toImage();
    testImage = testImage.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
    cv::Mat input_image = cv::Mat(testImage.height(), testImage.width(),
        CV_8UC3,
        const_cast<uchar*>(testImage.bits()),
        static_cast<size_t>(testImage.bytesPerLine())
    );
    emit imageAvailable(input_image);
}
```

Comment: Re. `"Visual Studio is showing a huge memory leak every time the function is called"`: how?  What exactly is it reporting?  Please show all warning/error messages as text verbatim.

Comment: I am seeing the process memory increase all the way to around 20 GB and then it resets and continues in a cycle. This doesn't happen if I comment the line 

QImage testImage = frame.toImage(); 

The rest of the program starts to behave in an unconsistent manner. After some time it halts in an Access Violation error, probably due to the memory being corrupted?

Comment: this code inside a loop or thread ? you should provide more code

Comment: It's inside a Thread

Comment: If threading is involved then you need to provide a lot more code/context -- preferably a [mcve].

Comment: Specifically, your `cv::Mat` `input_image` refers to (i.e. does *not* copy) the memory managed by the `QImage`.  If the `imageAvailable` signal is connected to a slot running on a different thread then -- assuming no deep copy of `input_image` is made along the way -- that slot will probably access memory that has already been freed when the `QImage` goes out of scope.  Hence undefined behaviour (as hinted at in your comment regarding inconsistent behaviour and access violation).

Comment: Even if I comment the emit and leave just QImage testImage = frame.toImage() line, the memory leak still appears

Comment: As stated in my previous comment you almost certainly have undefined behaviour elsewhere in your code -- this isn't a simple memory leak.  No-one can really help unless you provide more code -- preferably a [mcve].